# Proper use of PropertyChangedTrigger and ChangePropertyAction

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to set a default selected value when `ItemsSource` property changes on my `ComboBox`

My xaml :

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItemsSource, Mode=OneWay}" x:Name="c1">
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
         <ei:PropertyChangedTrigger Binding="{Binding ItemsSource,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
              <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="SelectedIndex" Value="{StaticResource zero}" TargetName="c1"/>
         </ei:PropertyChangedTrigger>                        
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>             
</ComboBox>
```

The SelectedItemsSource in my VM changes dynamically and I want to have the first item selected each time this happens .

Any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: What happens when you give your ComboBox a Name, and use ElementName in your Binding instead of RelativeSource?

Comment: it worked ... 
thanks .
i guessing maybe interaction triggers are not suppose to referee to elements as if it was relative to them with in the visual tree..

Comment: That'd be my guess. I'll repost the comment as an answer so that we can close this question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting property [IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem.aspx) to `true` for your combobox and remove the trigger completely -

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItemsSource, Mode=OneWay}"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">             
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: that actually did nothing .. 
i'll try it again and let you know

Answer (score 3):

has in addition to the current answers which led me on the way to my solution 
what i actually needed to accomplish is retrieving the last selected item when 
switching between itemsSources (plural)

from an article i found : 
       ["for each ItemsSource binding, a unique CollectionView is generated.."](http://shevaspace.blogspot.co.il/2008/06/when-selectorissynchronizedwithcurrenti.html)

i concurred that as long as the view exists each binding would generate its own CollectionView
and thus hold a reference to CurrentItem and CurrentPosition if decorated with

**IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"**

so i created my own **ChangePropertyAction** Class :

```
 public class RetriveLastSelectedIndexChangePropertyAction : ChangePropertyAction
 {                
    public int LastSelectedIndex
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(LastSelectedIndexProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LastSelectedIndexProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LastSelectedIndexProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LastSelectedIndex", typeof(int), typeof(RetriveLastSelectedIndexChangePropertyAction), new UIPropertyMetadata(-1));

    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        var comboBox = this.AssociatedObject as ComboBox;
        this.SetValue(LastSelectedIndexProperty, comboBox.Items.CurrentPosition);            
    }        
 }
```

and invoked it using  **PropertyChangedTrigger** as follows :

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItemsSource, Mode=OneWay}" 
           x:Name="c1" 
           IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">                                    
       <i:Interaction.Triggers>
          <ei:PropertyChangedTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=c1,Path=ItemsSource}">
              <local:RetriveLastSelectedIndexChangePropertyAction                   
                      PropertyName="SelectedIndex" 
                      Value="{Binding LastSelectedIndex}" 
                      TargetName="c1"/>
          </ei:PropertyChangedTrigger>                        
       </i:Interaction.Triggers>
  </ComboBox>
```

hope this helps if any one needing to retrieve their last selected item with out any messy 
code in their DataContext , enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your binding from:

```
<ei:PropertyChangedTrigger Binding="{Binding ItemsSource,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

to

```
<ei:PropertyChangedTrigger Binding="{Binding ItemsSource,ElementName=c1}">
```