# Select first item in list using SelectedIndex

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Combobox which defaults to the first item in the list from ItemsSource using

```
<ComboBox  x:Name="combo" 
           SelectedIndex="0" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding comboBoxSelections, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
           DisplayMemberPath="Key" 
           IsEditable="True" >
```

However, below doesn't bind properly to the a DataTable.
When I add binding to SelectedValue it now binds correctly but no longer defaults to the first item anymore;
`SelectedIndex="0"` isn't working now

```
<ComboBox  x:Name="combo" 
           SelectedValue="{Binding Selection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
           SelectedIndex="0" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding comboBoxSelections, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
           DisplayMemberPath="Key" 
           IsEditable="True" >
```

Is it possible to initialise the value in XAML only?

I don't think I can set it from the constructor as `combo` is not a single Combobox but part of a DataGridComboBoxColumn

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Department Id" x:Name="comboboxColumn1"
            SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Department Id}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="DataGridTempCol" Header="Selection">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox  
                      x:Name="combo" 
                      SelectedValue="{Binding Selection, Mode=TwoWay,   UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding comboBoxSelections, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"  
                      DisplayMemberPath="Key" 
                      IsEditable="True" >
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: So XAML can set it but you can't set it in code?  Really?

Comment: @Blam - I must admit C# is very new for me so I'm still feeling my way around and am probably asking obvious(stupid) things. It's not intentional. My code defines a DataColumn in a DataGrid and the XAML binds a Combobox to it so there is ComboBox on every row in that column. I can't see how to set `combo` SelectedItem = "0" in code?

Comment: I've tried to set the value explicitly using `row["Session"] = (KeyValuePair<string, double>)comboBoxSelections[0];` where comboBoxSelections is `this.comboBoxSelections = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, double>>();` but unsuccessful.

Comment: Read my words.  I said set the SelectedValue in code (not the SelectedIndex).  Drop the the SelectedIndex.   Two chiefs never works good.  You have a Property named Selection (I hope).  Just assign the the first row.

Comment: That's what my last comment is attempting to do. `row["Selection"] = (KeyValuePair<string, double>)comboBoxSelections[0];`. SelectedValue is a `KeyValuePair<string, double>` item. It's not allowing me to set it directly?

Comment: Oh God! I feel stupid now - It does work, it was a typo row["Session"]  instead of row["Selection"]. Thanks for being patient.

Comment: iv'e created a behavior that re-selects the last SelectedIndex 
or alternately selects index 0
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337442/proper-use-of-propertychangedtrigger-and-changepropertyaction/12341649#12341649

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the SelectedValue to the first row in the ctor.