# Prevent ListView.SelectedItem from being set to null when ChangeTrackEnabled is set

Tags: xaml, reactiveui

Given the following view model:

```cs
public class AttachmentsViewModel : ReactiveObject, ISupportsActivation
 {
     private ReactiveList<Attachment> _attachments;
     public ReactiveList<Attachment> Attachments
     {
         get => _attachments;
         set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged( ref _attachments, value );
     }

     private IReactiveDerivedList<AttachmentViewModel> _attachmentViewModels;
     public IReactiveDerivedList<AttachmentViewModel> AttachmentViewModels
     {
         get => _attachmentViewModels;
         set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _attachmentViewModels, value );
     }

     private AttachmentViewModel _selected;
     public AttachmentViewModel Selected
     {
         get => _selected;
         set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged( ref _selected, value );
     }
}
```

`Attachments` and `AttachmentViewModels` are set using the following code:

```cs
var items = DataManager.GetAttachmentsList();
Attachments = new ReactiveList<Attachment>( items ) { ChangeTrackingEnabled = true };
AttachmentViewModels = Attachments.CreateDerivedCollection( x => new AttachmentViewModel(x) );
```

`AttachmentViewModels` is bound to a `ListView`:

```cs
this.OneWayBind( ViewModel, vm => vm.AttachmentViewModels, v => v.List.ItemsSource );
this.Bind( ViewModel, vm => vm.Selected, v => v.List.SelectedItem );
```

However, if I update one of the Attachments via an AttachmentViewModel, then because `Attachments.ChangeTrackingEnabled` is set to true, the `AttachmentViewModels.CollectionChanged` is fired. For some reason, this in turn sets `List.SelectedItem` to `null`.

Is there any way to avoid this behaviour? Another SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13520744/23401) implies that this may be because I haven't implemented the appropriate equality operators in `AttachmentViewModel`. I tried following this advice, but it didn't seem to help.

Also, I had to set `ListView.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` to true - otherwise the `ListView` will not maintain the original selection. However, this doesn't prevent `SelectedItem` from being set to `null`, it just means that it is set twice. Once to `null`, then another time back to the original selection. This would be okay, except it results in visual glitches in the UI while `SelectedItem` changes.

Comment: Found a possible workaround - https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/1066. The author suggests caching the view models and re-using them (when the collection is reset)

Answer (score 1):

When the property of an item in a `ReactiveList` has changed and `ChangeTrackingEnabled` is `true` - the `CollectionChanged` event is fired. For an associated `IReactiveDerivedList`, this means that the entire collection is re-created. Since a new `AttachmentViewModel` is generated (for the same `Attachment`), `SelectedItem` no longer points to an item in the list. It's default behaviour is to become `null`.

By implementing a cache, the same `AttachmentViewModel` can be re-instated - in spite of the collection change event.

Based on this [ReactiveUI issue](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/1066), here's what I implemented:

```cs
public class AttachmentsViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Attachment, AttachmentViewModel> _cache = new Dictionary<Attachment, AttachmentViewModel>();

    private ReactiveList<Attachment> _attachments;
    public ReactiveList<Attachment> Attachments
    {
        get => _attachments;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged( ref _attachments, value );
    }

    private IReactiveDerivedList<AttachmentViewModel> _attachmentViewModels;
    public IReactiveDerivedList<AttachmentViewModel> AttachmentViewModels
    {
        get => _attachmentViewModels;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _attachmentViewModels, value );
    }

    private AttachmentViewModel _selected;
    public AttachmentViewModel Selected
    {
        get => _selected;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged( ref _selected, value );
    }

    public void LoadAttachments()
    {
        _cache.Clear();

        var items = DataManager.GetAttachmentsList();
        Attachments = new ReactiveList<Attachment>( items ) { ChangeTrackingEnabled = true };
        AttachmentViewModels = Attachments.CreateDerivedCollection( x => {
            AttachmentViewModel viewModel;

            if ( _cache.ContainsKey(x) ) {
                viewModel = _cache[x];
            } else {
                viewModel = new AttachmentViewModel( x );

                _cache.Add( x, viewModel );
            }

            return viewModel;
        });
    }
}
```

Note that the `Attachment` object has its own equality operators (based on an `ID` property). Users can revert their changes, so I had to add the `_cache.Clear()` to compensate.

Comment: Which makes me wonder, could this have been resolved by implementing the appropriate equality operator in `AttachmentViewModel`? Then `SelectedItem` would point to an item in the list. If equality was based on the underlying `Attachment.ID`, then maybe there is no need for the cache?