# WPF ComboBox event for ItemSource changed

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a particular collection which derives from `ObservableCollection`  and this type of collection I am binding to `ItemSource` of `ComboBox`. The problem is that when the `ItemSource` is changed the `SelectedItem` is ruined so I need to hook up the event of `ItemSource` changed so I can manually set the `SelectedItem` property.
I have tried to use `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` but that results in selecting the first item from the list, which in my case is not what I want because the `SelectedItem` is not first in the list. I have created a `Behavior` and attached to `ComboBox` but I can not find an event to hook up the `ItemSource` changes, also I can not rely on property changes of ObservableCollection cause in most cases the Collection has changes on the items in the list and there are no new items added or removed. I will post below my implementation.

```xml
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayZoneNumberSource}"
  SelectedItem="{Binding DisplayZoneNumberSelect, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ComboBoxSourceTemplateSelector}"
  VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:ComboBoxItemSourceChangedBehavior/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ComboBox>
```

```cs
public class ComboBoxItemSourceChangedBehavior : Behavior<ComboBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged;
    }

    private static void AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: "when the ``ItemSource`` is changed the ``SelectedItem`` is ruined" -> what do you mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242275/combobox-itemssource-changed-selecteditem-is-ruined

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: How can I catch the ItemSource changed event

Comment: Why not subscribing to `DisplayZoneNumberSource.CollectionChanged`?

Comment: Already said in my post that `CollectionChanged` it is NOT raising when you change a property of an item of the  collection

Comment: Okay so your question is actually about catching PropertyChanged events of all items in a collection, right?

Comment: Not exactly as this involves many changes and I want to find a quick workaround. Everytime when user enters in drop-down then ItemSource is updated with a new collection ( It might be same collection but sometimes it is a collection with new items/ removed items or modified items ) . Best solution for me would be to find an event that is raised when ItemSource is changed and I would manually select the SelectedItem

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms745795(v=vs.100) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764916/listen-to-changes-of-dependency-property

Comment: I will try same approach and see if I can get this working

Comment: Why do you update with new collection every time? Use the newly "typed in" item and add it to collection.

Comment: Because obviously I can not add it to the collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a custom class that inherits from `ComboBox`, there is a `protected` `OnItemsSourceChanged` method that you can override:

```
public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    protected override void OnItemsSourceChanged(IEnumerable oldValue, IEnumerable newValue)
    {
        base.OnItemsSourceChanged(oldValue, newValue);
        //...
    }
}
```

Obviously this method won't get called when a property of an individual item in the source collection is set. If you need to this, you need to hook up an event handler for the `PropertyChanged` of each item whenever an item is added to or removed from the source collection. And this require your type of items to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or some other interface that has a similar event.

Comment: Is there any event like `OnItemsSourceChanging` ? Because I can not use the one in the answer because it is too late and `SelectedItem` is already null